# Is XPath expression / a location step?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am wondering whether the XPath expression `/` is a location step.

I know that `/` is used to select from the root node, while a location step has an axis, a node test and zero or more predicates. Therefore I think that these two are unrelated and that the XPath expression `/` is NOT a location step.

Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/` is not a step in and of itself, rather it is a step separator as defined in production 26 http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xpath20-20070123/#doc-xpath-RelativePathExpr of XPath.

Per production 25, an expression beginning with a `/` is allowed, and the expression is evaluated starting from the root node.  But `/` it isn't actually a step, just an abbreviation of `root(self::node()) treat as document-node()`, optionally followed by `/` if there is another step.

Note that `//` is a syntactic abbreviation for `/descendent-or-self::node()/`.

In all cases the expansion of abbreviated portions of the location path address happens before evaluation.